# Angular + RxJS BehaviorSubject subscribe not working

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make some components friendship.
In AppComponent I get user pay balance in ngOnInit and subscribe for balance update. AppComponent is the root component. When user make a purchase in PaymentComponent, I want to set user pay balance in AppComponent. For these purposes I use BehaviorSubject in AuthService (singleton, import only in AppModule).

userInfo.getValue() in PaymentComponent is work, but in AppComponent subscribe() I don't receive any updates. What's the problem?

Thanks.

**AppComponent**

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: []
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   
   public balance: number;   

   constructor(private authService: AuthService)  { }

   ngOnInit() {
      
      this.authService.getUserProfile();

      this.authService.userProfile.subscribe(
        (data) => { this.balance = data; },
        (error) => {console.log("error"); }
      );
   }

}
```

**AuthService**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

   public userInfo = new BehaviorSubject<Users>(null);
   public userProfile = this.userInfo.asObservable();

   getUserProfile() {
      this.http.get<Users>(Globals.base_url + 'profile').subscribe(
         data => { 
            this.userInfo.next(data);              
         },
         error => {  console.log(error); });
    }
}
```

**PaymentComponent**

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class PaymentComponent implements OnInit {
   
   constructor(public authService:AuthService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.http.post(Globals.base_url + 'balance_write_off', body).subscribe(
         data => { 
                   this.authService.userInfo.next(data);
                  //this.authService.userInfo.getValue();
                 },
         error => console.log("error", error)
      );
   }
}
```

UPDATE. Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-enelht?file=src/app/payment.component.ts

Comment: does `this.http.post(Globals.base_url + 'balance_write_off', body)` return anything ? Did you set a console log in your subscribe to see if it emits something ?

Comment: Thank you for review.
Yes, this.http.post(...) return actual balance info.
console.log(this.authService.userInfo.next(data)) show me undefined.
this.authService.userInfo.getValue() return me actual balance too.

Comment: a console.log of a next call will return nothing anyway. is your payement component and app component are initiated at the same time ? 
Do as @Lashan Fernando says, It should work better. Always define your subscription before emitting anything.

Comment: AppComponent is root component in application. PaymentComponent initiated only when user makes a purchase.

Comment: Could you set your service @injectable decorator to `@Injectable(`{providedIn: 'root'})` and remove it from your app.module providers to see if it changes anything ?

Comment: I use Angular5. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Please create a stackblitz with your code, that makes helping a lot easier.

Comment: Here you are: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-enelht?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpayment.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Swipe subscription in `AppComponent`

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: []
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   
   public balance: number;   

   constructor(private authService: AuthService)  { }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.authService.userProfile.subscribe(
        (data) => { this.balance = data; },
        (error) => {console.log("error"); }
      );

      this.authService.getUserProfile();
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.
It didn't help. I have same result.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with your data types.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
   public userInfo = new BehaviorSubject<Users>(null);
   public userProfile = this.userInfo.asObservable();

   getUserProfile() {
      this.http.get<Users>(Globals.base_url + 'profile').subscribe(
         data => this.userInfo.next(data),
         // other stuff
      )
    }
}
```

`userProfile`s Observable is of type `Users`

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   public balance: number;   

   constructor(private authService: AuthService)  { }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.authService.getUserProfile();

      this.authService.userProfile.subscribe(
        (data) => this.balance = data,
        // other stuff
      );
   }
}
```

Here you try to assign the data, which is of type `Users`, to type `number`, which won't work.

Comment: Thanks, I fix this error, but I have the same result

Comment: I see, that your `this.http.post()` returns a number, right? What exactly did you fix? Because in this case, you try to push a `number` into an `Observable` which is of type `Users`. If you fix your types all over the files, it should work fine.

Comment: Yes, Marek, I fix type in this.http.post(), but I still don't receive updates in AppComponent subscribe().

Comment: So what types are you using at the moment? And where is the body in your `this.http.post` call coming from?

Comment: I'm using Users type now. I think body does not matter, because: 
1) I receive correct response from API; 
2) When I call `this.authService.userInfo.getValue()`, I get correct actual balance.
I would be grateful if you analyze Stackblitz. I delete all API-calls, replaced it with a simple Users object, but subscribe() in AppComponent still not receive any updates
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-enelht?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpayment.component.ts

Comment: Hm, I updated my Stackblitz-code and finally get new balance in AppComponent! Therefore problem is in my API-calls, in particular in PaymentComponent `this.http.post()`?

Comment: I am checking your StackBlitz

Comment: Your StackBlitz looks alright, your stuff gets updated. My assumption at the moment is, that either your 1) `.post()` has an issue with your body (even though its empty or not even initialised in your function OR 2) it is an timing issue, meaning that your `.post()` is quicker than your get, therefore your data from the `.post()` gets overridden

Comment: Thank you for your help, Marek. I will sort what's matter.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a problem with codes that was in the subscribe block. you can check with a Subscription variable that the Subscription is closed or not. If the Subscription is closed, your code are generating an error and thats why the subscriber is not working.